# VB.NET Do Until Loop to get the Month Name

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to get the month name from a `Do Until......Loop` and display in a `CheckedListBox`.

I have two tables.

**1. Month_Count**

[image: TableMonthCount]

**2. Fees_Ledger**

[image: TableFeeLedger]

My month name function...

```
Function mnthName(ByVal mnth As Integer)
    Dim name As String = String.Empty
    name = MonthName(mnth, False)
    Return name
End Function
```

To get the Month Details

`"SELECT FromMonth,ToMonth,MonthCount FROM Month_Count WHERE SemesterNumber='1'"`

And to get the Paid Count

`"SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotMonthPaidCount FROM Fees_Ledger WHERE SemYear='1' AND FeeId='1'"`

So...

```
' Got the values from queries


FromMonth = 7 '(July)

ToMonth = 6   '(June)

MonthCount = 12 '(Loop will rotate 12 times)

TotMonthPaidCount = 1 '(FeeId 1 paid one time)

'Declaring an integer variable
Dim StartM As Integer = 1

FromMonth = FromMonth + TotMonthPaidCount

' For the first month
CheckedListBoxMonth.Items.Clear()
CheckedListBoxMonth.Items.Add(mnthName(FromMonth))

' Now the loop to achieve the goal
Do Until StartM = (MonthCount - TotMonthPaidCount)
   If FromMonth >= 12 Then
       FromMonth = 1
       CheckedListBoxMonth.Items.Add(mnthName(FromMonth))
   Else
       FromMonth += 1
       CheckedListBoxMonth.Items.Add(mnthName(FromMonth))
   End If
   StartM += 1
Loop
```

This `Subroutine` results exactly what I want.

But the problem occurs when the `StartMonth = FromMonth (6) + TotMonthPaidCount (7)` value `>12`. As `13` or `14` or `15` has no Month Name, it is showing error.

> Argument 'Month' is not a valid value.

I want it like below.

[image: ListBoxMonth]

**What should I do ?**

Comment: Maybe if startmonth >12, substract 12 to startmonth?

Comment: @Pikoh could you please elaborate ?

Comment: `StartMonth = FromMonth + TotMonthPaidCount` `If StartMonth>12 Then StartMonth = StartMonth - 12 End If`